# Vertical highlight text in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, highlight, xcode9-beta, xcode9

In previous Xcode versions, we can vertical highlight text by press  and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key + drag mouse.
But in Xcode 9, when we press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key, Xcode change the cursor to "question mark", and will show "Search Symbol" result when we press mouse down.

Is there any new way to vertical highlight text in Xcode 9?